# WPF: adding Style to a slider

Tags: wpf, styles

I am using a Slider and putting a style element over it as follows... But however, I am not able to figure out why the style is not getting reflected. The RepeatButtons are not still visible.
Thanks in advance

```
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="Stroke_Gradient" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
            <GradientStop Color="#FF6E6E6E" Offset="0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0.496"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FF6E6E6E" Offset="1"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
        <Style x:Key="ScrollBar_RepeatButtonStyle1" d:IsControlPart="True" TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF6E6E6E"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFFFFFFF"/>
            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
            <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Rectangle Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <ImageBrush x:Key="zoomBkgrnd" TileMode="None" ImageSource="zoombg.png" Stretch="Uniform"/>
        <Style x:Key="{x:Type Slider}" TargetType="{x:Type Slider}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource zoomBkgrnd}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource zoomBkgrnd}"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Slider}">
                        <Grid x:Name="GridRoot">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <!-- TickBar shows the ticks for Slider -->
                            <TickBar Visibility="Collapsed" x:Name="TopTick" Height="4" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Placement="Top" Fill="{StaticResource zoomBkgrnd}"/>
                            <Border Grid.Row="1" Margin="0" x:Name="Border" Height="4" Background="{StaticResource zoomBkgrnd}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="2"/>

                            <!-- The Track lays out the repeat buttons and thumb -->
                            <Track Grid.Row="1" x:Name="PART_Track">
                                <Track.Thumb>
                                    <Thumb Width="10" Height="20" />
                                </Track.Thumb>
                                <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                                    <RepeatButton Style="{DynamicResource ScrollBar_RepeatButtonStyle1}" Command="Slider.IncreaseLarge"/>
                                </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                                <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                                    <RepeatButton Style="{DynamicResource ScrollBar_RepeatButtonStyle1}" Command="Slider.DecreaseLarge"/>
                                </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                            </Track>

                            <TickBar Visibility="Collapsed" Grid.Row="2" x:Name="BottomTick" Height="4" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Placement="Bottom" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="TickPlacement" Value="TopLeft">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" TargetName="TopTick"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="TickPlacement" Value="BottomRight">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" TargetName="BottomTick"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="TickPlacement" Value="Both">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" TargetName="TopTick"/>
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" TargetName="BottomTick"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource zoomBkgrnd}" TargetName="Border"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource zoomBkgrnd}" TargetName="Border"/>
                            </Trigger>

                            <!-- Use a rotation to create a Vertical Slider form the default Horizontal -->
                            <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Vertical">
                                <Setter Property="LayoutTransform" TargetName="GridRoot">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <RotateTransform Angle="-90"/>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                                <!-- Track rotates itself based on orientation so need to force it back -->
                                <Setter TargetName="PART_Track" Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal"/>
                            </Trigger>

                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: The slider is defines as below:

<Slider x:Name="zoomer" Orientation="Vertical" Minimum="20" Maximum="400" Value="100" Height="100" Width="20" ValueChanged="zoomer_ValueChanged" SnapsToDevicePixels="False" Margin="0,0,30,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" IsMoveToPointEnabled="False">

Answer (score 2):

here is your problem!

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type Slider}" TargetType="{x:Type Slider}">
```

to apply to all sliders, you should change to this:

```
<Style  TargetType="{x:Type Slider}">
```

to only apply to a certain slider, should change the x:Key to something like "MySliderStyle" and then, in the XAML where you declare your slider:

```
<Slider Style="{StaticResource MySliderStyle}"/>
```